# should I train the autoML model for a day?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I have 12,000 images spread acorss 12 categories. I uploaded and trained for 1 hour (free plan). I am not happy with the average percision of 20%
If I train the data for 6 or 12 hours, will I get better precision? If yes, will it be around 70 to 80%?

I am asking this because the training cost is very high and I am not sure if I will get good returns on the investment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mention in the [Image prediction pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/pricing#image_classification_prediction) that the Free plan runs for one hour and works only with 1,000 images. Meaning that your model didn't trained with your 12,000 images dataset. This might explain your low accuracy prediction.

Yes, the price per training hour is high, but you should consider paying so you will let your model training with your whole dataset.

I don't know if you'll get 70% or 80% accuracy, because **the accuracy of your model generally depends on how long you allow it to train and the quality of your training dataset.**

Hope this is helpful :D

Comment: I did not find any reference to free plan that runs for one hour and 1000 images. I can see the prediction plan limited to 1000 free images.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The prediction is the one with 1,000 images free. Sorry, my bad. I still think you should let it train more time. Maybe you're lucky and get better prediction results. Maybe your model gets overfitted. We won't know until you let it train more time.